# Get ownership of a Google Premium account with a reseller

Tags: downgrade

I have a client which have a Google Apps premium account which is attached to a reseller account.

How can I remove it from the reseller account and downgrade it to a free version of google apps ?

When I log into my the administration account I can choose between these two.

1. Renew my Google Apps for Business subscription with reseller.appspeople.dk
   Contact our reseller directly to renew your subscription and avoid any disruption to your service. To renew your service with another reseller, you can transfer your service.
2. Discontinue my Google Apps for Business service

Im affraid if I click number two that it will close down the Google apps account and delete the users.

What should i do?